# Adding dash to SQL insert without doing calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking to do a SQL Query like:

```
INSERT into table(number)
VALUE(3242-23423-234234)
```

The number is of type VarChar

Whenever I do the above it evaluates it like math.

Comment: try this INSERT into table(number)
VALUE('3242-23423-234234')

Comment: Thanks I don't know why i didn't try that.

Comment: No worries @Christoper hope I was able to helped you, I placed my answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put inside a single quotation because you're inserting a string/varchar value try this `INSERT into table(number) VALUE('3242-23423-234234')`

Answer (score 1):

Trying putting the value you're trying to insert in quotations

```
INSERT into table(number)
VALUE('3242-23423-234234')
```